# Reset cache after transaction commit in WSGI application

Tags: caching, flask, wsgi

Seems, it should be a common problem.

My Flask application has middleware that commits (if request processed normally) or rolls back (if request processing fails) SQLAlchemy session after each request. I need to implement cache for some object in DB, let's say User.

I'd like to implement manual invalidation, so when I change User object, I should remove it from cache. If next request needs User and it's not found in cache, it retrieve it from DB and cache.

OK, I changed User object and flush it (no commit yet, because next part of code can fail and transaction should be reverted). Seems, I can't invalidate object in cache immediately, because transaction's operation are still in pending mode, so if somebody else will try to access User's info, he will not find him in cache, so will retrieve outdated user from DB and cache him. So I need to remove User from cache only after transaction commit.

I thought about placing information about User needs to be removed from cache and executing removal in middleware, after DB transaction commits:

```
class DbSessionMiddleware:
def __init__(self, flask_app):
    self.app = flask_app.wsgi_app

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    try:
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
    except BaseException:
        dbs().rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        dbs().commit()
        # Check if error occurred and reset cache, if not?
```

Am I thinking in the right direction? How to pass data to middleware?

May be, use Flask-SQLAlchemy signals for this?